# PDF rendering in Metal iOS

Tags: swift, pdf, vector, render, metal

Im trying to render PDF file in my metal project, but I can't find solution how I can render page from pdf file unlike texture (not scalable). I need to do vector scalable texture, so I can scale and scroll. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a tiled-rendering approach and create large textures so that you can scale and scroll.

Comment: A large texture, eat a huge piece of memory. I think that it is possible to work with pdf as with fonts.

Comment: did you find a way? even I do have similar requirements.